# python: weird "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'FrontEndTestingStart'"

Tags: django, python-2.7

utils/frontend/urls.py

```
from utils.frontend import views
#more stuff
views.FrontEndTestingStart.as_view()
```

utils/frontend/views.py

```
class FrontEndTestingStart(APIView):
```

python reports

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'FrontEndTestingStart'
```

As if `views.py` would return None when importing.
Why is that?
I have a `__init__.py` in the directory

Comment: It could be that something in `more stuff` is shadowing/masking views.  What other code is there?  Also, your error message looks wrong  as it says it is looking for a `Frontendesting...`

Answer (score 0):

The object instance in FrontEndTestingStart is returning None. Hence the issue. For further clarification see these answers - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949265/5911972 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949272/5911972

Answer (score 0):

Here's what got my problem fixed - but  I don't know why.
Thanks to @2ps and @rohittk239, of cournse they are both right, but I couldn't find out WHAT exactly was causing that behaviour. Thanks both for trying to help.

I am trying to help a client run a software they bought. It's built on django 1.6.2 (yes I know it's dinosaur).

It had been configured on a long list of dependencies in requirements.txt. Most of them were fixed at a specific version with `==`, but some were not, and were on `>=`. When I then ran `pip install -r requirements`, this of course would install **newer versions than the ones specified** everywhere where there was a `>=` dependency.

Fixing the requirements.txt for all dependencies to `==` fixed the problem. Looks like some dependency in a later version would create a conflict.